# How do I install a virtual package?

Tags: package-management, packages, aptitude, ubuntu-15.10

I'm trying to install postgis with aptitude on Ubuntu 15.10 and is having problems with virtual packages that prevent the installation.

```
me@laptop:~$ sudo aptitude install postgis
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgdal1{ab} libgeos-3.3.3{a} libgeos-c1{a} libgif4{a} libhdf4-0-alt{a} libjson0{a} liblwgeom-2.1.8{ab} libmysqlclient18{a} libodbc1{a} libogdi3.2{a} odbcinst{a} odbcinst1debian2{a} postgis postgis-doc{a} 
  postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 11.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 31.6 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libproj0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

 liblwgeom-2.1.8 : Depends: libproj0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

 libgdal1 : Depends: libarmadillo2 (>= 2.4.2) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libdap11 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libdapclient3 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libepsilon0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libhdf5-serial-1.8.4 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.
 or
                     libhdf5-1.8.4 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libnetcdf6 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libpoppler19 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libproj0 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libspatialite3 (>= 2.4.0~rc2) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.

            Depends: libxerces-c28 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.
```

How do I install the virtual packages such as `libproj0`, so that I can get `postgis` setup?

Comment: Please show your `apt` `sources.list` file(s)..

Comment: Only tangentially relevant, but whoever named their package `libproj0` should almost certainly not be allowed to write software.